# Is there any way to use a common folder in both ios and android Application?

Tags: javascript, android, ios, webview

I am developing an application in both android and ios and there I am using the web view which is common to both platform..so my question is, Is there any way to make a common folder of webView and use in both android and ios? 
and If it is possible.if I made any changes in common folder it should reflect in both ios and android.
-please don't suggest to use ionic and cordova because my requirement is different.

I am not talking about update or commit. What I am asking is that when I make changes to some file inside common, the same changes should get reflected in both ios and android.
In the same way, the changes I make inside Android's common should get reflected in ios and the main common folder

Comment: For cross platform app, which framework you are using?

Comment: whats common folder ? iOS and android are two diff platform

Comment: I am not using any framework. I am developing both application in android studio and xcode differently..now there is a portion which is common to both so i thought to place that in a folder and use it in both places.

Comment: @Shubhank Yes I know but I have specific requirement like this..so I am asking for that...is this possible or not ?

Comment: why will apple IDE and android IDE have a common folder from which they will have things working ?

Comment: @shubhank I want to make bridge kind of thing because I don't want to copy and paste each and every time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code should be in version control, like git. You should create 3 repositories, one for each project and one for common. Add common as a sub repository for each project. Put all your html into the common repository. Include the folder that represents the common repo into each project.

Technically on disk the folder will generally be different for each project, but in the approach described above you can make changes, commit them and pull those changes into the other project easily.

Comment: Suppose I create 3 folders and in my common folder I make changes to the .html file.. will those changes get reflected in all the 3 folders i.e., in common, ios and android folders.. I am not talking about update or commit. What I am asking is that when I make changes to some file inside common, the same changes should get reflected in both ios and android.

Comment: Using this approach your would need to commit/push/pull in order to see the changes in the other folders.  Alternatively you could simply add the common folder to both projects (I haven't used Android studio, but Xcode doesn't care where the files are that you add to the project).  You could even use symbolic links in the file system to make the files appear in multiple places, but the version control approach seems the best to me

Comment: are you using version control? if not, why not? symbolic links aren't a good solution really...

Comment: Thanks you solution give me clue to move in right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Android's `WebView` implementation and iOS's `UIWebView` are written in different languages, run on different platforms and have different APIs. This means that you can't really re-use anything they have in common, even if the way you use them is very similar.